# Merge two astropy tables

Tags: astropy

I have two tables using [`astropy.table.Table`](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/table/), with an ID column that uniquely identifies each line. However, the lines are not necessarily all in the same order.

Table 1:

```
 ID | A
----|---------
123 | 1.38e11
456 | 5.31e8
789 | 1.92e10
```

Table 2:

```
 ID | B
----|----
123 | 42
789 | 13
456 | 70
```

I would like to create a table with three columns: ID, A and B.

Result of the merge:

```
 ID | A       | B
----|---------|----
123 | 1.38e11 | 42
456 | 5.31e8  | 70
789 | 1.92e10 | 13
```

I can add a column to a table

```
table1['B'] = [42, 70, 13]
```

however, the values have to be in the right order.

How can I merge these tables?

---

```
from astropy.table import Table

id = [123, 456, 789]
a = [1.38e11, 5.31e8, 1.92e10]
table1 = Table([id, a], names=('ID', 'A'), meta={'name': 'first table'})

id = [123, 789, 456]
b = [42, 70, 13]
table2 = Table([id, b], names=('ID', 'B'), meta={'name': 'second table'})

merged_table = ?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Astropy tables support a full set of database-like operations including merging, grouping, stacking and so forth.  Googling "astropy table merge" will get you to:

https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/table/operations.html

So in your case, simply do:

```
 from astropy.table import join
 merged_table = join(table1, table2, keys='ID')
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the `ID`s are the same in both tables (just not in the same order), first convert both tables to ndarrays, and transpose them so that columns in the table don't become rows in the array

```
import numpy as np

array1 = np.array([table1['ID'], table1['A']]).T
array2 = np.array([table2['ID'], table2['B']]).T
```

Then sort them by their first column

```
sorted1 = array1[array1[:,0].argsort()]
sorted2 = array2[array2[:,0].argsort()]
```

Make a new table merging the two

```
merged_table = Table([sorted1[:, 0], sorted1[:, 1], sorted2[:, 1]],
                     names=('ID', 'A', 'B'), meta={'name': 'merged table'})
```